# How do you get flymake to use a temporary directory for its temp files?

Tags: flymake

Flymake makes a bunch of `Foo_125113359859632_flymake.hs` files in my src dirs, messing up grep, tab-completion, LSP etc. Is there some setting or feature to get it to put temporary files in /tmp or ~/.emacs.d/tmp?

Answer (score 1):

Set `flymake-run-in-place` to `nil` and `flymake` will create temporary files in `temporary-file-directory`. See `C-h v flymake-run-in-place` and https://github.com/flymake/emacs-flymake/issues/32.

Comment: That's not Pavel Kobyakov/João Távora's flymake (which comes included with emacs), that's a fork by someone else. Guess I could switch to that, but then I might as well go back to flycheck if I'm using third party packages anyway …

Comment: ah well, nothing obvious to me in emacs's flymake. i guess you're using Haskell? maybe there's something haskell-mode's flymake integration.